# Positive definite bilinear form question

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I'm given that a quadratic form $q$ is *positive definite* if $q(v) > 0 \quad \forall 0 \neq v \in V$ and equivalently for bilinear form $\tau$. Does this mean that in a positive definite bilinear form there can exists $v,w \in V$ such that $\tau (v,w) \leq 0$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If $V=\mathbb{R},$ $\tau:(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is positive definite but $\tau(1,-1)=-1.$